# Cochran-Armitage test for ordinal / nominal contingency table in python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, statsmodels

I would like to apply a statistical significance test to a contingency table where the rows are an ordinal variable and the columns are a nominal variable.

[Statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/contingency_tables.html) implements tests for nominal/nominal (chi-squared) and ordinal/ordinal (linear-by-linear) contingency tables.

From my research, the appropriate test for ordinal/nominal appears to be an [Extended Cochran-Armitage test](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_09.html) [EDIT: Originally had Cochran-Armitage].

How can I apply an extended Cochran-Armitage in Python?

Comment: seems to be https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.contingency_tables.Table.test_ordinal_association.html

Comment: The statement in the `statsmodels` documentation *"Using the default row and column scores gives the Cochran-Armitage trend test"* is incorrect; the default is a linear-by-linear (ordinal/ordinal) association test. Cochran-Armitage is traditionally for one (nominal) two-category variable and one ordinal variable.

Comment: Isn't ordered and unordered the same for a binary variable?

Comment: Yes! You are right. Indeed I see that for a 2x3 table we have `table.test_ordinal_association(row_scores=np.array([1,0]), col_scores=np.array([0,1,2])).pvalue` equals `table.test_ordinal_association(row_scores=np.array([0,1]), col_scores=np.array([0,1,2])).pvalue` and any non-degenerate row scores (to most decimal places). So I take back what I said above. I see now what I need is what is called "Extended Cochran-Armitage" in [this article](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_09.html). I will amend the question.

Answer (score 1):

Called "test_ordinal_association" in [statsmodels.stats.contingency_tables](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.contingency_tables.Table.test_ordinal_association.html)

Credit to Josef, just turning his comment into an aswer